# For real matrices, if $A$ and $B$ are both positive-definite, show that all of $AB$'s eigenvalues are positive.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The original question goes equivalently like this

> For **real** matrices, if $A$ and $B$ are both positive-definite
>   Prove: all the eigenvalues of $AB$ are positive.

Facts that I know may have a role to play in the proof:
1) For real symmetrical  matrices, $A$ is positive-definite $\Leftrightarrow$ all eigenvalues of $A$ are positive.
2) Any real positive-definite matrix $A$ can be diagonalized as
$$A=Q^T\Lambda Q$$
where $\Lambda=\text{diag}\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \cdots,\lambda_n\}$ is the diagonal matrix comprising all the eigenvalues of $A$.
3).Any real positive-definite matrix $A$ can be decomposed as
$$A=P^TP$$
where $P$ is also a real positive-definite matrix that shares the same size with $A$.

However, I failed to make any progress after trying them all. Could you please help me with the proof or drop me a hint? Best regards!

---

**EDIT** I'd be specially grateful if you could explain it in a way that a student who has only taken an elementary linear algebra can understand. :) By saying "elementary", I mean I have only learnt real matrices and know very little about complex ones, to the point that I don't even really know what Hermitte is (⊙o⊙)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** Let $B^{1/2}$ be the positive definite square root of $B$. We have $AB=B^{-1/2}(B^{1/2}AB^{1/2})B^{1/2}$. Use [matrix congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence)(with [Sylvester's law of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_law_of_inertia)) and matrix similarity to finish the argument.

Note that the title and the body of your question do not match. While $AB$ always possesses a full positive spectrum when $A$ and $B$ are positive definite, $AB$ is not necessarily positive definite. For a counterexample, consider $A=\pmatrix{1\\ &3}$ and $B=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1+\epsilon}$ for any small $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I've just edited my title. But I still feel confused. The fact (1) is in my textbook as a theorem. So your counter-example proves that it's just false?

Comment: But $AB$ is similar to a positive-definite matrix

Comment: @Vim Except in some niche cases in Engineering, when we speak of the definiteness of a matrix, the matrix is assumed to be symmetric (if it is real) or Hermitian (if it is complex). For such a matrix $A$, it is positive definite iff it has positive eigenvalues. However, in the counterexample above, $AB$ is not even symmetric. So we cannot speak of its definiteness.

Comment: @user1551 oh yes I'm stupid!  I forget that the prerequisite is that the matrix is in quadratic form.

Comment: @Vim But in Engineering literature, sometimes a matrix $A$ is called positive definite when its symmetric part $\frac12(A+A^T)$ is positive in the conventional sense. In this case, we can speak of the (in)definiteness of any real square matrix, but as the above counterexample indicates, $AB$ may still fail to be positive definite.

Comment: @user1551 Sylvester's law of inertia is applicable for symmetric matrices. Here $AB$ and $B^{-1/2}AB^{1/2}$ are not symmetric.How can we apply here?

Comment: @mrka Thanks for catching that. It's now fixed.

Comment: @user1551 Now the matrices are not transpose congruent. From your expression it is clear that $AB$ is similar to the positive definite matrix $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$ via an invertible matrix. So they must have same eigenvalues. We do not need Sylvester's law of inertia here.

Comment: @mrka I don't understand your comment that "now the matrices (which matrices?) are not transpose congruent". I did use matrix congruence here: $AB$ is similar to $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$, and $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$ is congruent to $A$. Sylvester's law of inertia may be an overkill, but the fact that $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$ is positive definite IS owing to the fact that matrix congruence preserves positive definiteness.

Comment: @user1551 The matrices $AB$ and $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$ are not transpose congruent. I think you are trying to apply Sylvester's law to these matrices (Sylvester's law is true for transpose congruence, not for invertible congruence). Any way,  $AB$ and $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$ are similar via an invertible matrix, so the problem is solved. I am sorry, if I miss understood some thing.

Comment: @mrka。I have solved my question using @user1551's method. I think it's perfect.

Comment: @mrka Why is $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$ positive definite?

Comment: @Babai That's because $x^TB^{1/2}AB^{1/2}x>0$ for every nonzero $x$. Put $y=B^{1/2}x$ if you still don't see it.

Comment: @user1551 Thanx. On a different note, is it possible to prove if $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is positive semi-definite then $AB$ has all real eigen-values? ($A$ and $B$ are real matrices).

Comment: @Babai That's basic linear algebra. In general, if $X,Y$ are two rectangular matrices such that the products $XY$ and $YX$ make sense, then $XY$ has the same set of *nonzero* eigenvalues as $YX$. In particular, if both $X$ and $Y$ are square, then $XY$ and $YX$ have identical spectra. Therefore $AB$ and $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$ have identical eigenvalues. These eigenvalues must be real because $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$  is positive semidefinite.

Comment: $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$ may not be positive semi-definite as $A$ is only a symmetric matrix not a positive semi-definite matrix. I think you want say $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$ is symmetric.

Comment: @Babai Surely you are correct. I didn't notice that you have changed the conditions for $A$.