# Exercise about positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

I hope you're having a wonderful day. I'm stuck trying to solve this exercise from 'Linear Algebra' by author Marco Manetti. It's marked as a hard one, so I'm not surprised by its difficulty. However, since I have spent hours on it at this point, I would really like some closure and thus would appreciate if you could help me with hints or a solution.

The exercise is the following: "Suppose $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, positive semi-definite real matrices. Prove that $AB + I$ is invertible and that the eingevalues of $AB$ are nonnegative."

I have a proof of the fact that: "If $B$ is a real $n$ by $n$ matrix $B^TB + aI$ is invertible $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$."

Thus, my line of thinking has been the following: If I manage to write $AB$ as $C^TC$ for some matrix $C$, $AB + I$ is certainly invertible. Moreover, if $\lambda$ is negative real number $p_{AB}(\lambda) = \det(AB + (-\lambda)I) \neq 0$ as the argument isn't invertible because of the lemma. Therefore, $\lambda$ can't be an eigenvalue.
However, my whole argument crumbles apart because I don't know whether $C$ can even be proved to exist and, if that's the case, I don't know how to find it.

Any help is thoroughly appreciated.

Comment: It seems too much to hope that $AB$ can be written as $C^T C$, a symmetric matrix.  Since $A,B$ are symmetric, their product is symmetric only if they commute.  So you'll need another idea.  This [previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205741/for-real-matrices-if-a-and-b-are-both-positive-definite-show-that-all-of) might provide one.

Comment: Once you have that $AB$ has non-negative eigenvalues, then the eigenvalues of $AB+I$ are at least $1$ (same eigenvectors), so that matrix is invertible.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. Sadly I haven't studied anything about square roots of matrices yet, so I'm afraid I will have to come back to this thread and exercise in a few months if that knowledge is necessary to write a proof :(

Comment: Sometimes it helps to think about a special case, which might turn out to be equivalent to the general case when all is said and done.  Try the case when $A$ is *diagonal*.

Comment: if you don't know about square roots, just write $AB = (A)(B)= (Z^TZ)(M^TM)$ which has the same spectrum as $(ZM^T)(MZ^T) = (MZ^T)^T(MZ^T)$ (why?) --which is symmetric PSD so all eigenvalues are real non-negative